# Fill Quartz 2D line with custom Texture instead of UIColor

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, quartz-2d

So instead of this:

```
context?.setStrokeColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
```

I want to be able to fill / add a texture to those drawed lines.

I found out that you could use CGPatternCreate in Objective-C for this.

Does this apply to Swift as well and if so how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "somePatternImage.png")!).cgColor)`?

Comment: Would it be possible to do this with a UIVisualEffectView instead of an UIImage?

Comment: I was going to answer your last question, but you deleted it. A `UIVisualEffectView` uses the views behind it so have the effect you desire you would need to render the scene then apply a mask. I can give you an example if you republish your question.

Comment: Yeah I deleted it because the Question was not well formulated. It is republished now so you can show me your example. Thanks!